# How to reset a variable?

Tags: jquery, forms, variables, reset

I am making a maths equation and would like to have a reset button to reset all form inputs and variables stored. I managed to reset the input but not the variables.

*Here is my codepen*:https://codepen.io/ivy-chung/pen/GBzmwb?editors=1010

```
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("resetForms").reset();
  var average = 0;
  var total = 0;
  var avgGrade = 0;
}
```

Comment: Your variables are `var` scoped to the `myFunction` function.  They will be recreated every time that method is invoked.  There is nothing to reset for them at that point.

Comment: If you look at my codepen, the total, average score and grades do not change when i reset the forms. How can I do with that?

Comment: The variables you're resetting are local to `myFunction()`. Did you mean to act on global variables instead? Leave out the `var`.

Comment: I don't understand the "document.getElementbyId("resetForms").reset(); there does not seem to be an element in your code with the id resetForms.

Comment: @Ivy if your codepen has more information that you are not including in your question, you need to include it in the question.

Comment: Im sorry I forgot to save the file. You will be able to view it again. I would like to reset all variables in the 3 forms. Which basically like refreshing the page back to original.

Comment: Also if you are gonna use Jquery it is probably best if you used Jquery functions instead of html and not mix the two. Think `$("#resetForms").reset();` instead of  `document.getElementById("resetForms").reset();`